# Is the riddle solvable, or solvable is the riddle?

Tags: movies

If **Although** equals 5,

 and **The** equals 3.

 What does **It** equal

 Hint

> Main Actors: HF, CF, MH
>  Directed by GL

Please put in your answer if you used the hint

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> If we take "It is a dark time for the Rebellion. Although the Death Star has been destroyed" along with the clues given, we can count the words
>  and see what number the word actually resides on.

Clues:

Clue 1-

> If Although equals 5, (actual word number 9, four more than the clue)

Clue 2-

> and The equals 3. (actual word number 7, again, four more than the clue)

Clue 3-

> What does It equal (actual word 1, so what number is four less than 1)

So, the answer could be

> -3 .

And I had to use the hint

Comment: Yeah...I was thinking backwards. Will edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts:

> It seems the hint clearly points to the original Star Wars franchise (with main actors Harrison Ford, Carrie Fisher, and Mark Hamill, directed by George Lucas).
>
> I'm not sure what that has to do with the rest of the riddle yet. I noticed that the opening scroll for The Empire Strikes Back begins as follows: "**It** is a dark time for **the** Rebellion. **Although** the Death Star has been destroyed..."
>
> I suppose it's possible the riddle is somehow referencing this text, but I don't see any obvious way they relate to the numeric values given. And the words "although", "the" and "it" are so generic and ubiquitous that it's hard to think of other ways they relate to the Star Wars movies.

Comment: Both were typos, better fix them. Your line of reasoning is mostly correct, but you assume something critical.

Comment: The typos in question were the capital C and the asterisk. The C was a carelessly held shift, while the asterisk was from bolding the words

Comment: Note that rot13( bayl gur svefg svyz va gur bevtvany gevybtl vf npghnyyl qverpgrq ol Yhpnf).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis rot13 (V gubhtug gung Trbetr Yhpnf qverpgrq nyy gur Fgne Jnef zbivrf.)